# How to add a new item in right click context menu in Outlook Web App (OWA) exchange 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, outlook, contextmenu, add-in

When we right click on any email in OWA 2013, we get a context menu and by default it has some items like "Delete", "Flag", "Mark as read", "Move..." etc. I would like to add a custom item to this menu so that when I click on it it should open a new window.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and C#. Can someone please share the information or knowledge about this, how can I achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**On premises OWA**: You should be able to extend context menu of OWA on premises if you (or your customer) has access to OWA server and willing to add modifications. You may read more at [Outlook Web App Customization Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579439%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#User%20Interface%20Extensions%20File)

**Office 356**: Office 365 (Microsoft hosted OWA) is not exposing this extension point. You cannot add your own item into context menu. You may read on available extension points for OWA inside this document: [Office Add-ins platform overview](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins) (look for the "Outlook add-ins that extend functionality" section)

Comment: I didn't get it. So are you trying to say we can't add our custom item in context menu but same is possible in desktop version. There must be some way of doing this.

Comment: There is no way. Sure enough you can add context menu for Desktop Outlook by using COM/VSTO add-ins. There is nothing like this in Outlook add-ins (Office JS API)

Comment: I have edited my answer to include OWA on prem option